# How do I choose new lightning channels in order to minimize hops when rebalancing?

Tags: lightning-network, ln-opening-channels, ln-channel-balance-management

Currently my fees are quite high when I try to rebalance and I noticed that I can't rebalance some channels from any of my other channels. I have only six or seven channels and would like to expand to at least 10 for now.

Up until now my strategy for choosing nodes to open channels with was to use https://moneni.com/mcb/nodematch to maximise for the total number of nodes my node can reach with the least hops.